# Exit Code on Remote SSH session

Tags: bash, ssh, exit-code

I'm trying to capture the exit code of a remote SSH script:

```
ssh remoteuser@server"
        exit_on_error() {
          exit_code=$1
          if [ "$exit_code" -ne "0" ]; then
            >&2 "echo command failed with exit code ${exit_code}."
          fi
          echo "exit_code is $exit_code"
        }

        ls -la blah
        exit_on_error $? !!
"
```

What I'm getting is:

> ls: cannot access blah: No such file or directory
>
> bash: line 3: [: -ne: unary operator expected
>
> exit_code is

`blah` certainly does not exist.  I'm just trying to capture the exit code of that command.  I thought it was with local vs remote variable expansion so I tried escaping $1 and whatnot but to no avail.  I tried putting it all in a `bash --login -c` block but no change.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: well dammit that was easy.

@MarkPlotnick that should be the answer :)

Comment: What are the `!!` supposed to do? `exit_on_error` doesn't look at any of its other arguments.

Comment: @chepner oh sorry:  what I pasted above was much slimmed down version.  !! is capturing the last command.  I was adding that to an echo statement to give more info.

Comment: by the way, if you want to use a local variable remotely wrap double-quotes in a single:  `"'$STOP'"`

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the variables are parsed by bash before the string is send to the server. You can omit this by either use single quotes to wrap the code send, or create the function on the server with `typeset`. Note that the latter option still needs to escape the variables directly used in the string.

Single quote:

```sh
$ ssh user@server ' 
function exit_on_error { [ $1 -eq 0 ] || echo "ERROR"; }
ls filethatdoesntexist
exit_on_error $?
'
```

Create command:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

function exit_on_error {
    [ $1 -eq 0 ] || echo "ERROR";
}

ssh user@server "
$(typeset -f exit_on_error)
ls filethatdoesnotexist
exit_on_error \$?
"
exit 0
```